# Integrating an OAuth login with users in a database with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been searching around the internet for a while and I can't seem to find documentation to really help me with what I'm looking to do:

I'd like to implement a login that utilizes OAuth to and matches it to a users in my own database. Only users who have successfully logged in via OAuth and exist in my database would get granted access.

I've tried implementing a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` with the built in `@EnableOAuth2Client` and `@EnableWebSecurity` annotations provided by spring but that creates a separate `Principal` for the users who login via OAuth.

I'm not sure exactly what classes need to be overwritten such that the user first logs in via OAuth, is then match with a user in my database, and results in a `Principal` with the granted authorities specified in my own database.

This is the tutorial I've been following but I don't think it fits my use-case:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/